# Taylor expansion of leapfrog scheme about step size

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, power-series

I'm reading a paper but there is a part that I cannot figure out. So we have $y=(q,v)^T$ and $F(y)=(v,f(q))^T$ where all functions are assumed smooth, and we have the Stormer-Verlet scheme
$$\Phi_h(q,v)=\begin{pmatrix}q+hv+\frac{h^2}{2}f(q) \\ v+\frac{h}{2}f(q)+\frac{h}{2}f(q+hv+\frac{h^2}{2}f(q)) \end{pmatrix}.$$

I want to get a Taylor series expansion of the form
$$\Phi_h(y)=y+hF(y)+h^2D_2(y)+h^3D_3(y)+\cdots$$ where
$D_2(q,v)=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} f(q) \\f'(q)v\end{pmatrix}$, and $D_3(q,v)=\frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ f'(q)f(q)+f''(q)(v,v)\end{pmatrix}$, but I have no clue how to obtain these terms. Here we have a vector field but we are expanding about a real number $h$, I am not familiar with such Taylor expansions. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could help me out.